# JDBC: [337]: INTO clause not allowed for this SELECT statement

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

In HANA, I want to obtain the latest ID value and assign it to a variable.

```
DECLARE MAXID BIGINT;

SELECT MAX(ID) INTO MAXID FROM "SAPABAP1"."APPLOG";
```

But this returns an error saying;

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [337]: INTO clause not allowed for this SELECT
>   statement

Note that the data type of ID is also BIGINT.

Any idea why I'm getting this error and any solution to get the max ID and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added DO BEGIN END and it worked.

```
DO BEGIN

    DECLARE MAXID BIGINT;    
    SELECT MAX(ID) INTO MAXID FROM "SAPABAP1"."APPLOG";

END;
```